# Use a component from external module

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I've an external module called "MHC", inside this module i've a component called "PdfViewer". How can i use that component inside another APP that imports the module?

I'm doing this right now :

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [IonicModule, HttpModule]
.
.
.
    exports: [PdfViewer]
})
export class MHCModule { }
```

Inside my APP :

```
 @NgModule{(
    .
    .    
    .
    imports: [MHCModule]
    .
    .
    .
    )}
```

I get this error :

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load pdf-viewer.html ; Zone:
>    ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load pdf-viewer.html
>   undefined

UPDATE :

I don't know if is important but, inside my component.ts, i declare my .html and .scss in this way :

```
@Component({
templateUrl : 'pdf-viewer.html',
styleUrls: ['pdf-viewer.scss']
})
```

Am i missing something important?

Thanks at all,
Giorgio.

Comment: Where does `pdf-viewer.html` come from?

Comment: So you declare `PdfViewer` in your `MHCModule`? You have to put it in your `exports` AND your `declarations`.

Comment: @yurzui Same directory of the component inside the module.

Comment: @MichaelSolati added. same problem.

Comment: Can i UP this, please?